# How to create Directory/File into IIS using ASP.NET C# Entity Framework

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, iis-7.5

My work environment is:

- Windows 7 Professional
- Visual Studio 2019, ASP.NET MVC, Entity Framework
- SQL Server Express
- IIS Version 7.5 (installed locally)

When I debug in Visual Studio, the directory/file is created without problem inside this path `~/Content/Documentacion/log/` (using IIS Express that comes with VS).

But when I publish the solution and run it using IIS 7.5, the directory/file is not created, I cannot understand the problem.

This is the code:

```
public void CreaLogATiempos(DateTime fin, bool sobrescribir = false)
{
    try
    {
        text = "xxxxx= ";
        string docPath = "~/Content/Documentacion/log/" ;
        var folder = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath(docPath );

        if (!Directory.Exists(folder))
        {
            Directory.CreateDirectory(folder);
        }

        FileInfo MyFile = new FileInfo(System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath(docPath + this.archivo));

        if (!MyFile.Exists)
        {
            StreamWriter crear = new StreamWriter(System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath(docPath + this.archivo));
            crear.WriteLine(text);
            crear.Close();
        }
        else
        {
            StreamWriter crear = new StreamWriter(System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath(docPath + this.archivo), true);
            crear.WriteLine(text);
            crear.Close();
        }
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Exception: " + e.Message);
    }
}
```

Maybe someone can see the error or has an idea about the problem?

Comment: Log exception to file, it may help. But i think, problem in permissions of IIS process login.

Comment: Looks like a permissions issue to me; when you run it from IIS does the app pool user have create directory permissions ? And yes. what Backs said - some logging will help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can I introduce you to `TextWriterTraceListener`? Add this to your **Global.vb** file:

```vb
'adding tracing to a log.
Trace.Listeners.Clear()

Dim stream As New IO.FileStream(Server.MapPath("~/App_Data/trace.log"), IO.FileMode.Append)
Dim writer As New IO.StreamWriter(stream, System.Text.Encoding.UTF8)

Dim logListener As New TextWriterTraceListener(writer, "trace.log")
Trace.Listeners.Add(logListener)
Trace.AutoFlush = True

Trace.WriteLine($"{DateTime.Now.ToString} - class: Global.asax - method: Application_Start - message: Trace listener loaded.")
```

Create a **trace.log** file inside `"~/App_Data"`

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. The OP's question is C# related. Please provide C# code, not VB.

Comment: Thanks @PeterCsala the question is asp.net related. Does my answer address his issue? I think so. I'll be more careful next time.

Comment: @PeterCsala finally, your code was able to create a file into IIS. I  had  translated it to C#. The only problem that I have now is that after to create the file, I can´t read it, I need to stop IIS to access but, I think it is related to "FileAccess" property into my code.

Comment: @Byron2017 It is not my post, I've just edited. The kudos goes to Typing.

Answer (score 1):

- Select the project in visual studio and press ALT + Enter to open the settings property of that project as following picture

[Picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gGOHC.png)

You can use this folder in your controller as following way

```
var physicalPath = Server.MapPath(Settings.Default.CompanyImagePath);
```

Comment: You can used following function to check the directory status. if it exists or not and if not exists it will create at the server that directory.

`public static bool CheckFolderExists(string appFolderName)
        {
            //var appDataPath = Server.MapPath(Settings.Default.CategoryImagePath);
            if (!Directory.Exists(appFolderName))
            {
                Directory.CreateDirectory(appFolderName);
                return true;
            }
            else
            {
                return true;
            }
        }'